# Makefile call function. How to get all arguments

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I define a custom function in a Makefile, like this

```
define add_target
${1}: ${2} ${3}
endef
```

How can I get a list of all arguments, that have been provided to `$(call add_target, ...)`?

So:

- `$(call add_target, A, B)` will be expanded to `A: B`
- `$(call add_target, A, B, C, D)` will be expanded to `A: B C D`

[GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html) only says that

> When make expands this function, it assigns each param to temporary variables $(1), $(2), etc. The variable $(0) will contain variable. There is no maximum number of parameter arguments.

but nothing about how to get all params.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no way, except by writing out `$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 ...`  Of course no matter how many variables you enumerate the caller could have used more.

However, in your example the simplest thing to do is just pass two arguments: the target name and the prerequisite list (as a single argument).  So it would be:

```
define add_target
${1}: ${2}
endef

... $(call add_target, A, B)
... $(call add_target, A, B C D)
```

(no commas separating the prerequisites in the list)

Comment: Everyday I get more and more angry at what utter garbage GNU Make is ... >8^(

Comment: Oh my, I had to read it like 5 times to get what was happening here, I just couldn't see the absence of commas. u_ù thank you !

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, it helps to use a recursive call in make, e.g.

```
R=$(wildcard $1)$(if $2,$(call $0,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9),)
```

but usually `$(foreach)` works better. The caveat is that there is no way to handle infinite number of parameters, and the formula above stops at the first empty parameter, i.e. you cannot skip one in the middle.